# Are there any tools that allow you to track and manage test cases and test execution?

Tags: testing, test-management, requirements-management

For the bugs or issues, there are now many good issues trackers available which allows status and tracking issues and also allows you to organize it to manage specific releases.

I am looking for test case tools should be able to support listing of functionality and test cases with possible linkage to them, allows test suits or test plans (as group/ hierarchies) to organize them. Some of the potential usage could be to identify list of key test cases that must be executed if particular functionality or modules are affected.

Also Additional parameters to support related to system of execution. It would be best if result of execution of tests can be recorded with necessary comments. Web interface and possible email notifications could be essential.

Please note that i am *NOT* looking at test automation systems like cruise control etc. but more as a system for testing management. I am more keen to see a system that allows visualization of Traceability matrix. Open source projects are most appreciated, though please also suggest if there is commercial software.

Are there any tools that allow you to track and manage test cases and test execution?

Comment: does TestLink fall into this category?

Comment: @rwong, yes, Test Link is actually the closest to what i find and planning to use.

Answer (score 2):

We are using the Bugzilla/Testopia package. You can link specific Test Cases in Testopia back to specific Bugzilla entries. This gives you ability to trace the resolution of a bug (or feature) to a specific Test Case.

The Testopia feature set is *decent* for managing Test Runs. We use it to track running full regression tests (manual QA) on various products. (We also use some separate automated test tools to supplement the manual QA.)

There may be better packages out there.  We were already using Bugzilla for bug tracking, so it was natural to incorporate Testopia as well.

Comment: Is testopia really stable for use now? and is it necessary to use Bugzilla for use of testopia? Is there a demo i can see somewhere?

Comment: Testopia is definitely stable in the release we are using (2.4). I wasn't the one who installed it, so I'm not sure if it is a separate install from Bugzilla. Check out their home page: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/ for more details. Our QA person uses it, so I'm not the expert (I just occasionally check testing progress with it.)  We've been using it for 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

At a previous job, we used ApTest with some success.

It was useful to implement test run results (for traceability requirements), and also to clarify expectations during development (the test cases were disclosed before dev was complete).

The product is web-based and you could comment during testing.

I do not think you could define sw modules and link to test cases. But you could organize releases and group test cases (with multiple levels of hierarchies).

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not free, Microsoft Test Manager does what you're asking for. If you have VS2010 Ultimate, it comes with it.

It supports running test cases (both [automated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff472576.aspx) and [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380763.aspx) in virtualized or non-virtualized environments) and tracking the (history of) results of the runs.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for helping you with test management.If you haven't yet selected a tool perhaps you should consider TestWave (http://www.testwave.co.uk). It is a commercial, hosted test management solution which allows you to create your test scripts, execute them, store any details about the run (including attachments) and also to raise bugs or defects. You can even link your test cases to requirements and releases to make your testing easier to keep track of.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this company ? If so you should [state it](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) because this answer looks a bit spammish in its actual form.